# Flatten nodes that have repeated child node using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a document of following structure (this is just an example to help me verbalize the problem), that I'm trying to flatten. By flattening I mean copying all the `<Report_Entry>` nodes with several `<Event>`s so that each `<Report_Entry>` node contained just a single `<Event>`

What I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-06</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-10</End_Date>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-10</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-15</End_Date>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-15</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-20</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-20</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-25</End_Date>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-25</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-30</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-30</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-10-05</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-06</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-10</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-10</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-15</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-15</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-20</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-20</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-25</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-25</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-30</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-30</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-10-05</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Here is XSLT that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
  <xsl:for-each select="Event">
    <Report_Entry>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::Event)]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Report_Entry>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works, though I feel that there might be a better, faster and more universal solution. In particular, I don't like "hardcoding" `<Report_Entry>` since this way I wouldn't be able to copy its attributes (if any). Are there other ways/templates to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Report_Data>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Event"/>
  </Report_Data>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Event">
  <Report_Entry>
   <xsl:copy-of select="../ID | ."/>
  </Report_Entry>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-06</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-10</End_Date>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-10</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-15</End_Date>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-15</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-20</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-20</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-25</End_Date>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-25</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-09-30</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Event>
      <Start_Date>2011-09-30</Start_Date>
      <End_Date>2011-10-05</End_Date>
    </Event>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Report_Data>
   <Report_Entry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Event>
         <Start_Date>2011-09-06</Start_Date>
         <End_Date>2011-09-10</End_Date>
      </Event>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Event>
         <Start_Date>2011-09-10</Start_Date>
         <End_Date>2011-09-15</End_Date>
      </Event>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Event>
         <Start_Date>2011-09-15</Start_Date>
         <End_Date>2011-09-20</End_Date>
      </Event>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Event>
         <Start_Date>2011-09-20</Start_Date>
         <End_Date>2011-09-25</End_Date>
      </Event>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Event>
         <Start_Date>2011-09-25</Start_Date>
         <End_Date>2011-09-30</End_Date>
      </Event>
   </Report_Entry>
   <Report_Entry>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Event>
         <Start_Date>2011-09-30</Start_Date>
         <End_Date>2011-10-05</End_Date>
      </Event>
   </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer couldn't be much simpler, so no need to worry on that front. When writing code, but especially XSLT, the clarity of the code tends to be worth a lot more than its ultimate efficiency.

As for the hardcoded element name and copying attributes, here's a start:

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
  <xsl:variable name="parent-name" select="name()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="parent-attributes" select="@*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="Event">
    <xsl:element name="{$parent-name}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$parent-attributes"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::Event)]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

`variable`s are used to stash some of the context as it exists outside the `for-each`. `element` makes an element that's a look-alike for your original, no matter what it's called, and the first `copy-of` makes it more convincing by copying in the original's attributes as well. Now, if your data suddenly takes on attributes, you'll be ready.

The non-hardcodedness of the name doesn't mean much in this case, but it would if, say, you were to factor out that part to a separate template and call it from multiple places:

```
<xsl:template name="collapse-the-thing">
  <xsl:param name="context"/>
  <xsl:param name="sub-element-name" select="'Event'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="parent-name" select="name($context)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="parent-attributes" select="$context/@*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$context/*[name()=$sub-element-name]">
    <xsl:element name="{$parent-name}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$parent-attributes"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../*[name()!=$sub-element-name]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
  <xsl:call-template name="collapse-the-thing">
    <xsl:with-param name="context" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Some_Other_Entry">
  <xsl:call-template name="collapse-the-thing">
    <xsl:with-param name="context" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="sub-element-name" select="'Happening'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope that was enlightening. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really enlightening and helpful! :) I'll save your flexible example for later, and will make use of first one. BTW, if I want to apply other transformations while flattening the document, I can replace <xsl:copy-of select="%xpath%"> for <xsl:apply-templates select=%xpath%">, right?

Comment: Yeah, you could actually replace them (the latter two `copy-of`s) with any number of other things depending on what you're looking for the output to be. `apply-templates` will of course apply the top-level `template` rules to the matching children of the current node (which within the `for-each` is your `Event` element). See also the `mode` attribute if you'd like to apply a separate set of rules for just this case.